# How to make sure that data that has been retrieved from a server is not re-retrieved every time a fragment is called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, server

I am working with fragments and a navigation drawer. I have two fragments and a fragment manager to recycle them when I click on the menu items in the navigation drawer. I am also receiving data from a server in one of the fragments.

However, every time I reinitialize the fragment, the call to the server occurs again. I would like to know if there is any way that I can make sure that the server call only occurs in the beginning and when I click the refresh button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is any way that I can make sure that the
>   server call only occurs in the beginning and when I click the refresh
>   button.

Yes , when you click on the refresh button use an `ClickListener` to trigger the call.

If you want the call to occur only when fragment is created you can refer to the fragment life cycle. The better way is to put this call in the `onCreate()` method.

However if you don't want to make a call each time the fragment is created i recommend you tu use the SharedPreference to save the information that call have already been made.

exemple:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // The seconde value of method getBoolean incates the default value if constant not found
        if (prefs.getBoolean(Constants.CALL_DONE, false)) {
            // Make call
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(Constants.CALL_DONE, true).apply();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the Constants.CALL_DONE?